# Wix add package to bootstrapper without starting automatically

Tags: wix

I have a package (`optionalSetup.exe`). Is there possible with wix to add this package in my bootstrapper but don't execute it when setup is perform ?

My question is probably not clear due to my bad english, I will try to explain more with concrete case.

I have a C# project: `myApplication.exe`

I have a Wix setup: `mySetup.msi`

I have a bootstrapper: `myAppSetup.exe`

I have an optional install file: `optionalSetup.exe`

I want that the generation of bootstrapper create a Release folder containing `myAppSetup.exe` and `optionalSetup.exe`. Running `myAppSetup.exe` will install `myApplication.exe` by calling `mySetup.msi` but NO `optionalSetup.exe`. `optionalSetup.exe` is just there and can be called by user by clinking on it if he need to.

How can I write the Bundle.wxs to do that?

Comment: Create a .MSI installer that installs (copies) optionalSetup.exe, and then add this .MSI to the Bootstrapper.

Comment: That could work but there is no simple way ? I thought about creating a exepackage but with special install condition to have the package in Release/Debug folder with myAppSetup.exe but without run it.

Comment: A Bootstrappter isn't used to install things, it's used to run things. It can run things that installs things though.